# Use IntelliJ to debug a Gradle Execute Task

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have the following Gradle task:

```
task execute(type:JavaExec, dependsOn:['build']) {
    main = 'com.something.Main'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

When I debug the task in IntelliJ I get the following error:

```
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
:execute FAILED
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

It seems later versions of IntelliJ Idea cannot connect debuggers to forked test runners when using the Gradle Test runner.

In your sources root, add a `gradle.properties` file with the next two lines:

```
maxTestForks = 1
testForkEvery = 0
```

That should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. When I was invoking Gradle in IntelliJ, the Java environment by default contained

```
JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:59842,suspend=y,server=n
```

I removed the `JAVA_OPTS` from the environment all together and *voila*, no more JDWP error because no more JDWP.

Comment: where I can remove this options?

Comment: In the run configuration

Comment: I don't have any JAVA_OPTS filled in the run configuration. Are you talking about debugging server/external code? I have problem with debugging local gradle task

Comment: sorry. It's **VM options**